# Numerically find the minimum distance between given point and the curve of given function.

Tags: numerical-methods, roots

Let $f\colon\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$ and $\mathbf{x}_0\in\Bbb{R}^n$. How could I (numerically) find the minimum Euclidean distance between the curve $f(\mathbf{x})=0$ and $\mathbf{x}_0$, granted that $f$ is given analytically. I am looking for an numerical solution in $C$ programming language.

Apologies if this question does not fit the site's requirements, but I think I would have more luck in MathSE, rather than in StackOverflow.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean the minimum distance between $x_0$ and a level set of $f$?

Comment: Of course, I mean the curve $f(\mathbf{x})=0$. I will edit right now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Minimize $F(x) = f(x)^2 + |x-x_0|^2$. The gradient is $\nabla F(x) = 2( f(x)\nabla f(x) + x-x_0)$.

Comment: Thanks @HansEngler, but what's the intuition behind that? I think that I heve to minimize $\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0\|_2^2$ subject to $f(\mathbf{x})=0$. Is that equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an optimization problem with on equality constraint. By the method of Lagrange multipliers, you have to consider the function
$$
L(x,\lambda)=\frac12\|x-x_0\|^2 + λ·f(x)
$$
and find critical points for it. These satisfy
$$
0=f(x)\\
0=\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=x-x_0-λ·\nabla f(x)
$$
which you can try to solve via Newtons method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @LutzL. Just another one: Granted that $L$ is non-linear and differentiable, would you suggest the BFGS or L-BFGS method (quasi-Newton), or something else?

Comment: That depends on the problem and its dimension. For small dimension, up to 10 or so, I'd say Newton, for dimensions larger than 100 certainly some quasi-Newton or trust-region/SQP method.

Comment: How do you choose the starting point here in the case of applying newton's method?